# How to update a label in intervals using threads in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my code:

```
private void firstlabel()
    {
        doDisplayUpdate("klg");
    }

    private delegate void doDisplayUpdateDelegate(string result);
    private void doDisplayUpdate(string text)
    {
        if (this.label2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.label2.Invoke(new doDisplayUpdateDelegate(doDisplayUpdate), text);
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = "Saving";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            label2.Text = "Saving.";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            label2.Text = "Saving..";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            label2.Text = "Done";
        }
    }
```

firstlabel() is being called by a created thread like this:

```
Thread ms = new Thread(new ThreadStart(firstlabel));
        ms.Start();
```

What I want to do it basically update a label 3 times (the label is not visible by default). What happens is that it runs but it label2's text is "Done" and doesn't show the previous strings such as 'Saving', 'Saving.' or 'Saving..'.

The parameter in doDisplayUpdate when firstLabel() methodis called is just for testing purposes. I have tried looking at background worker threads as well as Task but really couldn't understand them.

Comment: How would I then be able to pause the thread so it continues running the code after 0.5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

By calling `Thread.Sleep()` where you are, you're locking up the UI thread. It can't update the `Label` until your method is done running, so you don't see any updates.

Instead, call `Thread.Sleep()` in the other thread, and only call back to the UI thread when you want to update the `Label`.

This will work better: *(but I'd recommend reading about those alternate methods you mentioned)*

```
private void firstlabel()
{
    doDisplayUpdate("klg");
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    doDisplayUpdate("Saving");
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    doDisplayUpdate("Saving.");
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    doDisplayUpdate("Saving..");
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    doDisplayUpdate("Done");
}

private delegate void doDisplayUpdateDelegate(string result);
private void doDisplayUpdate(string text)
{
    if (label2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        label2.Invoke(new doDisplayUpdateDelegate(doDisplayUpdate), text);
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = text;
    }
}

...
...

label2.Visible = true;
Thread ms = new Thread(new ThreadStart(firstlabel));
ms.Start();
```